# Split a string with bracketed elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, split

I am solving a problem from codewars and I'm stuck on a step

I have a strings like this `defr[fr]i##abde[fgh]ijk`  and i want add separatar between element ,but that should be the case for elements inside brackets ,
so the output should be `[d,e,f,r,[fr],i,#,#,a,b,d,e,[fgh],i,j,k]`

I have tried looping with different conditions,

and I came up with this code

```
        if land[i] == "[":
            print(land[i])
            j = i +1
            while land[j] != "]":
                print(land[j])
                j +=1
            else:
                number_of_shelter.append(land[i:j+1])
        else:
            continue
```

but it appends only bracketed elements

can someone tell me the approach that how can i append other elements along with bracketed ones

OTHER EXAMPLES:
`##[a]b[c]#`>>> `[#,#,[a],b,[c],#]`

`[a]#[b]#[c]` >>>
`[[a],#,[b],#,[c]]`

Comment: You [asked this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70538124/string-splitting-on-brackets) earlier and received a good answer (basically : `re.findall(r'\[.*?\]|.', s)` ). But you deleted that question and are posting a dupe. If the answer wasn't correct you should explain what other constraints you have.

Comment: Why `#,#a`?  Why is the first `#` a separate element, but the second one is joined to `a`?

Comment: @JohnGordon h,it's a mistake in writing

Comment: @Mark ,actually that question got closed , yes ,you are right  I had not made the question fully clear ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works :

```
def foo(s):
    output = ""
    inBracket = False
    for i in s:
        if i == "[" or (inBracket == True and i != "]"):
            output+= i
            inBracket = True
        else:
            inBracket = False
            output += i + ","
    if output[len(output)] == ",":
        output = output[:-1]
    return output
```

Comment: This will put a comma after the last character.

Comment: @JohnGordon Thank you for pointing that out, fixed !

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code

```
str = "defr[fr]i##abde[fgh]ijk"
arr = []
in_the_bracket = False
for i in str:
    if i == '[':
        in_the_bracket = True
        chr = ''
    if in_the_bracket:
        chr = chr + i
    else:
        arr.append(i)

    if i == ']':
        in_the_bracket = False
        arr.append(chr)
print(arr)
```